# How can I get $\int_{\Bbb R^n}e^{itu_1x_1}dP^{X}=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{iu_1x_1}dP^{X_1}$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, integration

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space and $X=(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ a random vector on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ such that 
$$
X_k:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to({\Bbb R},{\mathcal B}_{\Bbb R}), k=1,2,\cdots, n
$$
are random variables, but *not necessarily independent*. What I need to show is that
$$
\phi_X(u)=\phi_{X_1}(u_1)
$$
where $u=(u_1,0,0,\cdots,0)\in{\Bbb R}^n$, and $\phi_X$ is the characteristic function of $X$:
$$
\phi_X(u)=\int_{\Bbb R^n}e^{it\langle u,x\rangle}dP^{X}
$$
where $P^X$ is the probability distribution measure of $X$. By simple calculation, 
$$
\phi_X(u)=\int_{\Bbb R^n}e^{iu_1x_1}dP^X.
$$

> My **question** is: How can I relate this integral with 
>   $$
>  \phi_{X_1}(u_1)=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{iu_1x_1}dP^{X_1} ?
> $$

Formally, what I tried is that (in the case $n=2$)
$$
\begin{align}
\phi_{X_1}(u_1)&=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{iu_1x_1}dP^{X_1}\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{iu_1x_1}dP^{X_1}\int_{\Bbb R}dP^{X_2}\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R}\left(\int_{\Bbb R}e^{iu_1x_1}dP^{X_1}\right)dP^{X_2}\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{iu_1x_1}P^{X_1}\otimes P^{X_2}
\end{align}
$$
But $X_1,X_2$ are not necessarily independent and I'm not able to get
$$
P^{(X_1,X_2)}=P^{X_1}\otimes P^{X_2}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you treat them as integrals on $\Omega$ instead of integrals on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\phi_X(u)=\int_\Omega e^{i\langle u,X \rangle}\,\mathrm{d}P=\int_\Omega e^{iu_1X_1}\,\mathrm{d}P=\phi_{X_1}(u).
$$